# php array plus foreach syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I have problem in writing the below syntax php syntax:-

simple array syntax:

```
$array = array(
"a" => 1,
"b" => 2,
"c" => 3
)
```

simple foreach syntax:

```
foreach ($countries as $key => $value){
echo $key; echo $value;
}
```

Now, I would like to combine the above 2:-

```
$array = array{
foreach ($countries as $key => $value){
 $key => $value,
}
}
```

how can I write it? or I can only construct a string look like the words inside the array bracket?

Comment: do you want to merge both array?

Answer (score 5):

you should write

```
foreach ($countries as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$array =$array+$country;

print_r($array);
```